# Print some HashMap element

Tags: java, methods, printing, hashset

I'd like to develop an HashSet of Object that have some fields inside, for example:

```
public class Thing{
    String one;
    String two;
    String three;
    getter and setter (...);
    toString (...);
}
```

And also to create some methods to print just some of these Thing(s).
For example:

```
void printAll_Thing_With_This_One("string to compare with one");
void printIf_Two-And_Three_Are_Equals();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Its very possible. What is preventing you?

Comment: I don't know how to do it!

Comment: It is always better to show what you have already tried. Once we can see what you have tried, we can assist with fixing any issues there might be. If you are completely new to programming, a tutorial site may be a better source of information for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printThingWithOne(Set<Thing> things, String one) {
  for(Thing thing : things) {
    if(thing.getOne().equals(one)) {
      System.out.println(thing);
    }
  }
}
```

If any of that confuses you, you probably need to read/study more before asking more questions.

Comment: It doesn't confuse me, i didn't think i could use the foreach statement for HashMap also, i always used it for ArrayList.
Really helpful, thanks :)

Comment: Well you cannot use it for a `HashMap`, only a `HashSet`. For a `Map`, you need to iterate over the keys (`Map#keySet`), values (`Map#values`) or each key/value pair (`Map#entrySet`).

Comment: How can i understand where i can use the foreach?

Comment: Anything that implements `Iterable`.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day.
One last thing.. every Hash* Object has better performance than ArrayList in insert/delete/print actions, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. And not sure what a print action is. But inserting / deleting from a hash structure should be O(1), where inserting into a list structure could also be O(1).